# Make a group presentation with an array look better

Tags: arrays

I have written a presentation like that, but I want a way to make it look better.

```
$$\left\langle \begin{array}[t]{l|cl}
A_{13}, A_{32}, A_{21} &(A_{13}-t_{13,1})(A_{13}-t_{13,2})=0&\\
&(A_{32}-t_{32,1})(A_{32}-t_{32,2})(A_{32}-t_{32,3})=0& A_{13}A_{32}A_{23}=1\\
&(A_{23}-t_{23,1})(A_{23}-t_{23,2})(A_{23}-t_{23,3})=0&
\end{array}
 \right\rangle$$
```

Comment: Surely you have to remove the `[t]` option to `\begin{array}`.

Comment: And drop the `$$....$$` -- replace it with `\[...\]`

Answer (score 1):

May be some thing like this will look better:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \[\Biggl\langle 
       \begin{array}{l|cl}
                        & \mathcal{B} = 0 \\
            \mathcal{A} & \mathcal{C} =0  & \mathcal{D}=1 \\
                        & \mathcal{E} =0  &                                             
        \end{array}
     \Biggr\rangle\]
where
\[
\begin{aligned}
  \mathcal{A} &= A_{13}, A_{32}, A_{21}\\
  \mathcal{B} &= (A_{13}-t_{13,1})(A_{13}-t_{13,2})\\
  \mathcal{C} &= (A_{32}-t_{32,1})(A_{32}-t_{32,2})(A_{32}-t_{32,3})\\
  \mathcal{D} &= A_{13}A_{32}A_{23}\\
  \mathcal{E} &= (A_{23}-t_{23,1})(A_{23}-t_{23,2})(A_{23}-t_{23,3})
\end{aligned}
\]
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Disclaimer: `\mathcal` is chosen randomly. I don't know whether this changes the meaning or not. This is just meant to convey an idea.